# How can I modify html from an ajax call before adding it into document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm performing an ajax call to grab an HTML page from the server;  ajax call looks like this:

```
function loadHtml() {
    $.ajax({
          type          :  'GET',
          async         :  false,
          url           :  'my.html',
          contentType   :  'text/html',
          dataType      :  'html',
          success       :  function(data) {
              loadedHtml = data; // the loadedHtml variable is global
          }
    });
}
```

Later, I'd like to display this html after modifying it somewhat.

---

### Attempt 1

I tried this, but the resulting screen shows nothing at all (body contains no html).

```
var myContent = $(loadedHtml).find('#test1').text("Modified!");
$('body').html(myContent);
```

---

### Attempt 2

I also tried this, but the resulting screen just shows the original content of `loadedHtml`.

```
var myContent = $(loadedHtml);
myContent.find('#test1').text("Modified!");
$('body').html(myContent);
```

---

### Original Html

Here's the original content of `loadedHtml` from `my.html`

```
<div id="test1" style="color: white;"> Working! </div>
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

---

### UPDATES

1. This is a simple example I'm trying to get to work before adding the complexity of what I really need to be doing.  So, using a simple string replace on the `loadedHtml` variable before inserting it into the DOM is not something that will work for me.
2. I've updated my code to show the ajax call is synchronous.  the `loadedHtml` variable does in fact contain the html from the server by the time I get to the point I'm trying to modify it.

Comment: @gdoron loadedHtml is a variable that I'm using to store the response from my ajax call. So after the ajax call, it contains the string "<div id="test1" style="color: white;"> Working! </div>"

Comment: Well. Did you inserted it to the DOM? I guess not...

Comment: @gdoron it gets inserted into the DOM when I call $('body').html(myContent).  I am trying to modify it before inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: Don't forget the AJAX call is asynchronous. Where does the code that modifies the response? If it is not inside the _success_ function how can you guarantee that the AJAX call has completed before you attempt to modify the response?

Comment: @andyb - I've left some details out for simplicity, but I do verify that the ajax call has completed and the loadedHtml actually contains the expected html before attempting to modify it.  I'll try to improve my question.

Comment: @csturtz OK, I'm also thinking that you might want to specify `dataType: 'html'` in the [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. jQuery isn't 100% perfect at guessing the correct type of data and pulling HTML via AJAX has caught me out like this in the past :)

Comment: @andyb - I've added the `dataType: 'html'` in the ajax call. nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misuse the `find` function:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, **the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements** in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

**It search only descendants, In your case `#test1` isn't a child...**

so this:

```
$('<div id="test1" style="color: white;"> Working! </div>').find('#test1')
```

Won't grab the test1 element, it's not a  descendant.

Comment: Well, I admit it : jQuery is definitely not my thing. So, I suppose he could just enclose it(the initial `test1` block, I mean) in another `div` or something, huh?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon. You can do this: `$(loadedHtml).wrap('<div></div>').parent().find('#test1')` But then you will just get `$(loadedHtml)` so... WHY? **:)**

Comment: I ended up just modifying the `my.html` file so that the current contents were wrapped in an additional div.  This allowed the existing javascript to produce what I originally was looking for.

Comment: @csturtz. My advise is: Read all the API docs on each jQuery function you use. Don't use functions that you only think you know what they are doing, Know what they are doing! **Good Luck!**

Answer (score 1):

O.K.  If I "read" the question + comments right, Your code is outside the success function.
You guys have to remember. `ajax` is async!  move your code inside the success handler.

*"The 'A' in AJAX stands for asynchronous."*

> But how can the response be used in context of a function? Consider this flawed example where we try to update some status information on the page:

```
function updateStatus() {
     var status;
     $.ajax({
         url: 'getStatus.php',
         success: function(response) {
             status = response;
         }
     });
     // update status element?  this will not work as expected
     $('#status').html(status);
}
```

> The code above does not work as desired due to the nature of asynchronous programming. The provided success handler is not invoked immediately, but rather at some time in the future when the response is received from the server. So when we use the 'status' variable immediately after the $.ajax call, its value is still undefined. The next snippet shows how we can rewrite this function to behave as desired:

```
function updateStatus() {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'getStatus.php',
         success: function(response) {
             // update status element
             $('#status').html(response);
         }
     });
}
```

jQuery [FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions)

Comment: Well, if the code IS outside the `success` function... then I think you got us all... by surprise... (I took that for granted)

Comment: I've updated my question.  The ajax call is not asynchronous... and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: @gdoron I just noticed too : just look at HIS comment below MY answer. If he really DID try ".replace" and it worked, he must be in the right track about it... huh?

Comment: @csturtz. It's kind of guessing game. Show all of your code please!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you've already managed to print `loadedHtml` in the first place (and that there's nothing wrong with your AJAX call), try this...

```
loadedHtml.replace("test1","modified");
```

And print it out... ;-)

Comment: using .replace() on the original string before adding it to the document works fine.  The problem is that I need to make more complex changes.  I'm just trying to get this simple example working before I introduce more complexity.  I'll update my question to be more specific.

Comment: @csturtz Have you tried `alert(myContent)` first? So as to see (taking for granted that there is no issue NEITHER with the Ajax call, NOR with the way you try to process the result), which of the following 2 statemens is faulty...