# modify html data before adding it into the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify the data returned by an ajax call from an external webservice before adding it into the document similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959278/how-can-i-modify-html-from-an-ajax-call-before-adding-it-into-document)

```
success: function (data) {
   $(data).find(".page td:nth-child(4)").hide();
   $("div.resultstable").html(data);
}
```

data is in the following format

```
<div class="results">
   <div id="page1" class="page"
      <table>
         <tr> ... </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="page2" class="page">
      <table>
         <tr> ... </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I add `$(".page td:nth-child(4)").hide();` to my success function after the html(data) line   it works but I am trying to modify data before adding it into the document.

Comment: Try [`documentFragment`](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/). Another alternative is to `$('<div>').append(resp).find('.it')`, which now that I think about it, may actually create a `documentFragment`. Just don't forget to maintain a reference to the `$('<div>')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the data

```
success: function (data) {
   $(data).find(".page td:nth-child(4)").html("some data");

//or 
   $(data).find(".page td:nth-child(4)").append("some data");// to add some data

   $("div.resultstable").html(data);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to save the reference to the object(s) returned? For instance, here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KsBBd/ The content does get logged to the console as having been styled, but immediately after it's appended to the `body` with no change.